# Unknown column in eloquent query builder laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

The relationship between gwrcategory and gwrproces is one to many. Between gwrproces and gwrlist is many to one.

I use this code to search in the data. I use % for now to find everything until this works.

```
    $searchresult = GwrCategory::
    whereHas('gwrproces', function($query) use ($request){
        $query->where('gwr_code', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->input('gwrcode').'%')->
        whereHas('gwrlist', function($query) use ($request)
        {
            $query->where('versie', 'LIKE', '%');
        }
    )->with('gwrlist')->get();
    }
)->with('gwrproces')->get();
```

The resulting sql of the code above is:

```
select * from `gwr_proces` 
where `gwr_proces`.`gwr_category_id` = `gwr_categories`.`id` and `gwr_code` LIKE %20% 
and exists 
(select * from `gwr_lists` 
 where `gwr_proces`.`gwrlist_id` = `gwr_lists`.`id` and `versie` LIKE %)
```

This gives an error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'gwr_categories.id' in 'where clause'.

I've played around with the query in phpmyadmin and this seems to get it working. I only added `gwr_categories` to the first select * from.

```
select * from `gwr_proces`,`gwr_categories` 
where `gwr_proces`.`gwr_category_id` = `gwr_categories`.`id` and `gwr_code` LIKE '%' 
and exists 
(select * from `gwr_lists` 
where `gwr_proces`.`gwrlist_id` = `gwr_lists`.`id` and `versie` LIKE '%')
```

My question is: how can I convince eloquent to add the correct column or rewrite the code to get it to search in gwrproces and gwrlist tables for a specific text in a column while keeping the relationship with categories in-tact?

Edit: I use eager loading, hence the with()->get()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you execute the nested query.
You also can't use eager loading like that.

Remove `->with('gwrlist')->get()`.

Comment: Follow up question: I get too many results, I'd like only the matching results. I get all the gwrprocesses within the same category instead of only the matching proces.

Comment: You have to add the constraints from `whereHas('gwrproces'` to the `GwrCategory::gwrproces()` relation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, do I do this in the model file? Could you please give an example? I've been struggling with this for hours, can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Comment: I started a chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166981/room-for-jonas-staudenmeir-and-imqqmi

Comment: I've found out that I need to combine whereHas (to filter down categories, though still containing all processes), then use with on the whereHas closing bracket, then where is the same that's in whereHas, this filters down the processes.